# php loop over array that has been sent from html form with the same variable name

Tags: php, arrays

this is my html code:

```
<input name="dependencies[]"
```

and in php i do this:

```
 $dependencies = $_POST['dependencies'];
```

and when I do this:

```
print_r($dependencies);
```

I can see the values like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => )
```

#### My question

I want to add each value from that array to another array:

I didn't know how to do that

I tried:

```
foreach ($dependencies as $number){
echo $number;
}
```

but nothing has been printed

#### Update

this is the html

```
<input name="dependencies[]" value="<?php $question->id; ?>" type="checkbox" <?php if($db->does_question_depend_question($questionID, $question->id) == 0){}else{echo "checked";} ?> />
```

and I can see the check boxes checked or not when I run the page

#### Update2

the whole code

```
 <form action="../DB/addDependencies.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="questionID" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Porgugese Name</th>
                <th>Englisn Name</th>
                <th>Dependent</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
foreach ($questions as $question) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $question->ptName; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $question->enName; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="dependencies[]" value="<?php $question->id; ?>" type="checkbox" <?php if($db->does_question_depend_question($questionID, $question->id) == 0){}else{echo "checked";} ?> />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
}
            ?>
        </table>
            <input type="submit"  value="Save" name="submit" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Because you don't have values in the array?!

Comment: @Rizier123 so what wrong did I do in the html please?

Comment: Show us your html And the entire php script

Comment: Did you fill in the form @MarcoDinatsoli?

Comment: @Rizier123 I showed you the code

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Do you even have a form or just the input type? You would have to submit the form!

Comment: @Rizier123 I added the whole form code

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Did you checked any of the checkboxes? Also do you get any errors? (Add error reporting with: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
foreach ($dependencies as $key=>$val){
var_dump($key);
var_dump ($val);
}
```

instead of

```
foreach ($dependencies as $number){
echo $number;
}
```

;-) hope that will bring some ideas to your mind in this case

Comment: if $number='' is output will be the same for both functions? ?? really?

Comment: is it stand-up show? use var_dump to get it! :-) Elon Than just told you :-)

Comment: sure, you are right, but why don't you offer to echo $_POST? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your HTML to this:

```
<input name="dependencies[<?php $question->id; ?>]" type="checkbox" <?php if($db->does_question_depend_question($questionID, $question->id) == 0){}else{echo "checked";} ?> />
```

Then to test if a checkbox if checked you just need to do something like

```
function isQuestionChecked($question_id) {
    return isset($_POST['dependencies']) && isset($_POST['dependencies'][$question_id]);
}
```